# Eclipse не могу добраться до .java .class

Tags: eclipse

[image: Банки с вареньем]

Раньше было пару папок,где лежали файлы .java/.class, что-то произошло и теперь папка src не открывается,если открыть папку в проводнике(в виндоусе)-там все на месте.
Как вернуть все назад?
Почем стали видны эти файлы .jar и папка src не доступна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменял перспективу на java и все вернулось на круги своя.
Window->Perspective->Open Perspective